# Get percentage at specific time in a CAMediaTimingFunction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

```
CGFloat start = 0;      // The start value of X for an animation
CGFloat distance = 100; // The distance X will have traveled when the animation completes

CAMediaTimingFunction* tf = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints:0 :0 :1 :1]; // Linear easing for simplicity

CGFloat percent = [tf valueAtTime:0.4]; // Returns 0.4

CGFloat x = start + (percent * distance); // Returns 40, which is the value of X 40% through the animation
```

How can I implement the method `valueAtTime:` into a category of `CAMediaTimingFunction` so that it works like described in the code above?

Please note: This is a contrived example. I will actually be using a non-linear timing functions with a UIPanGestureRecognizer for a non-linear drag effect. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered calculating progress by checking the presentation layer's in-flight value of the property being animated?

Comment: Unfortunately, that will not do. I am animating the view manually when the user drags her finger.

Comment: In other words, I'm setting the value myself, not handing off that responsibility to a CAAnimation.

Comment: And before I set the value, I want to manipulate it with a timing function, hence the `valueAtTime:` method.

Comment: Restating my previous comment. You might find an alternative approach easier and more powerful. You can drive core animations interactively, thus leveraging the full power of CA, by manipulating the `CAMediaTiming` properties. Basically you set `speed` to zero and update `timeOffset` based on the progress of your interactive gesture. And if you want to finish the animation automatically, just set the media timing properties back to normal. [See here](http://ronnqvi.st/controlling-animation-timing/?utm_campaign=iOS_Dev_Weekly_Issue_117&utm_medium=email&utm_source=iOS%2BDev%2BWeekly)

Answer (score 2):

A timing function is a very simple Bezier curve - two endpoints, `0,0` and `1,1`, with one control point each - graphing time (x) against percentage of the animation completed (y), so all you have to do is the Bezier curve math (given x, what's the corresponding y). Google for it and you'll readily find the necessary formulas. Here's a decent place to start that I found: http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/

Answer (score 0):

Timing function has to axes (progress and time). If we take your example, we can handle all animation by ourself. I can change animatable property each frame. Here is how we can achieve it using display link.

```html
final class CustomAnimation {
  private let timingFunction: CAMediaTimingFunction
  private var displayLink: CADisplayLink?
  private let frameAmount = 30 // for aniamtion duration 0.5 sec
  private let frameCount = 0
  
  init(timingFunction: CAMediaTimingFunction) {
    self.timingFunction =  timingFunction
  }
  
  func startAnimation() {
    displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(updateValue))
    displayLink?.add(to: .current, forMode: .default)
  }

  func endAnimation() {
     displayLink?.invalidate()
     displayLink = nil
  }
  
  @objc
  private func updateValue() {
        guard frameCount < frameAmount else {
            endAnimation()
            return
        }

        frameCount += 1
        let frameProgress = Double(frameCount) / Double(frameAmount)
        let animationProgress = timingFunction.valueAtTime(x: frameProgress)
        /// count yout value. change position of ui element and e.t.c
        let value = ....
    }
}
```